# Opened imagemagick using terminal, not sure how to close it now

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I opened imagemagick through the terminal with $ display filename.jpg

Once it opened, the terminal was in use (?) as in no more prompt, just blank space where I could type anything like when you write to a file with 'cat'. I used CTRL + Z to get back to the prompt and the image stayed open in imagemagick. Now I can't close it - clicking the red X on the window doesn't do anything. How do I close this window/program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type `fg` in the terminal to bring the stopped job back to the foreground.  Then the red X should work again.

Comment: For completeness: You could also use `bg` to resume the job in the background. Then the red X should also work again.

Answer (score 4):

By pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button, this window closed down.